# Will Ubuntu One be available in spanish?

Tags: ubuntu-one, localization

¿ Estará disponible Ubuntu One en español?

Tanto la web, como los foros y las FAQs están en inglés solamente, al parecer.

Gracias por su generoso esfuerzo e invaluable trabajo.

PD: Uso la versión 11.04 Natty Narval de Ubuntu.

---

Will Ubuntu One (The Web Front-end), FAQs and Forums, etc., be available in ***spanish*** ?

Thanks for your invaluate work and effort.

P.S:I use Ubuntu version 11.04  Natty Narwhal

Comment: Help Tnranslate them...

Comment: Except for the FAQ the rest of what you just mentioned is in Spanish.

Comment: I find it really weird that till now there is no spanish version for it (and other apps). Taking into consideration that there is a bigger spanish population in the world than all english native speakers combined. Its the second language spoken in the world and the second in the US with a very big percent of the whole population of the US let alone almost all south and central countries. That is one huge puppy there. I speak spanish (Venezuela) and sometimes the fact that there is no way to transmit some knowledge in other than english limits one.

Comment: Funny fact: A big chunk of the developers of Ubuntu One speak Spanish as their native language.

Answer (score 3):

There are no plans to translate the website into any language in the foreseeable future.